# ctrl + key in terminal always uses standard keymap

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, terminal, keyboard-layout, gnome-terminal, dvorak

I am on Ubuntu 10.4. My standard keyboard is QWERTZ, but I usually use the Dvorak layout.

When I type inside the GNOME terminal, the layout is the one I set in keyboard preferences (e.g. Dvorak). However, as soon as I use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[key]</kbd>, the keys are remapped to the QWERTZ layout. For example if I want to hit <kbd>Ctrl,</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, I actually have to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>j</kbd> in Dvorak.

This only happens in the terminal, and only for applications that run *inside* the terminal. Shortcuts of the terminal (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> for copying) use the correct current keymap.

Any suggestions how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and it drove me crazy.  You have to change the order of the keyboard layouts:

- Click on the keyboard icon (or System->Preferences->Keyboard)
- Go to Layouts
- Click on the Dvorak Layout and click `Move Up` until it's at the top

It seems that Gnome uses the top one for the keyboard shortcuts, but all of the other programs use the current layout.  I don't think there's a way to have Gnome use the current layout for it's shortcuts.